# PHP_AUTH_USER not set?

Tags: php, http-authentication

For some reason, none of the code within

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) &&
    isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
{

// When the above is set, the code that is here will execute of course

}
```

is being executed for me. When I enter the correct username and password, the prompt box for the authorization again pops up. Wouldn't both fields be 'set' if they are correct and I press enter? But for some reason that is not the case. What can I be doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 83):

There is a 'sensible way' to use HTTP Basic Auth in CGI-mode PHP: in the .htaccess use

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

and in the PHP use

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = 
  explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

Comment: For some reason, on my server I had to use $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']

Comment: This works but each page returns a 404 not found even though the page is displayed properly

Comment: Sorry, I'd picked up the following rewrite from another page: RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L] and the trailing L was causing my 404 errors

Comment: This worked for me with just the RewriteRule line in .htacess. I didn't have to make any changes to the PHP, and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` are now set.

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php#L47

Comment: The above didn't work for me but it might be due to my server set-up. On my Ubuntu 14.04 and ServerPilot set-up, I used the following in my `.htccess` file `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1`. I can then access it using `$_ENV['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` in PHP.

Comment: Can anyone explain the RewriteRule in this reply? It worked for me, but I actually do not understand it. :-)

Comment: try first to check if the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` is set and not empty then you can use `list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = 
  explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));`, because some servers same in my case has `REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` index and not `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` so better set a full condition for both offsets.

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki This one only worked for 1and1 shared hosting server.

Comment: There is a better answer below :) the one from @thePanz

Answer (score 27):

try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

on your .htaccess file which you will have to place into the root directory

and then

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

in the begining of your php scripts

Comment: @garyJ, It's the length of "basic "

Comment: can you explain to me why this line is needed in .htaccess? It worked for me

Answer (score 13):

I am using Symfony 2.5.7 running on PHP-PFM + Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.
I have BASIC_AUTH working, it needs to correctly configure the Apache VirtualHost by adding:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

as also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17490827/435956).

Comment: same here: PHP running in PHP-FPM mode, apache 2.4, centOS. I just had to add that line to my vhost config and it worked perfectly, with no changes on the PHP side

Answer (score 11):

Starting from Apache 2.4.13, you simply need to use [CGIPassAuth](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#cgipassauth) directive in your .htaccess:

```
CGIPassAuth On
```

Comment: this is the correct solution in my opinion, the others are workarounds

Comment: Best new feature, fixed me right up.

Answer (score 3):

According to `phpinfo()`, my server API is CGI/Fast CGI, so I've solved the problem by putting the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`.  This works for me on a PHP 5.3 CGI + Apache installation.

Comment: Seems not to work under a Plesk installation with LAMP (sorry, I have no idea what version of Plesk this particular provider is using; Apache is the old 2.2 and PHP the even older 5.3.3).

Answer (score 2):

If user access is granted giving username/password in URL please check if

```
AuthType Digest
```

is entitled in your VHost/Directory/.htaccess configuration.

This fixed it for my use case.

Answer (score -3):

On my host's servers, use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER']` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`