# CPanel PHP_AUTH_USER behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, http, cpanel, authentication

I am ruining the following code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

Straight from the PHP website. However, When I run this script on a CPanel server it just keeps prompting me for my login details. Whereas it works fine on a server not running CPanel.

Any ideas? Obviously a configuration issue here.

Thanks

Comment: Is Apache using PHP as a module or are you using `suphp` or anything similar? Check EasyApache in WHM to find out..

Comment: Dunno what do you call "CPanel server" but this code works only with mod_php, not CGI

Comment: Yup, PHP running in the wrong mode is most likely your problem - there is at least one question asking for a workaround here on SO. Might be worth searching for, I think it was somehow CPanel related, too.

Comment: Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php `The HTTP Authentication hooks in PHP are only available when it is running as an Apache module and is hence not available in the CGI version.`

Comment: There an easy way of getting around this without changing CPanels configuration?

Comment: @James I think basically no. I can't find the duplicate I was talking about (it had sme ingenious workaround ideas) but I think there is no easy way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP_AUTH_USER not set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663520/php-auth-user-not-set)