# PHP Undefined Index error -- cannot solve

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I have tried the solution provided in stack overflow for this problem but could not really solve this problem.

I am working on the code written by someone else. The code is as follows

```
$web_user = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"];
$file_name = $web_user.'_nefops_var_sel.tab';
$state['dumper_file_name'] = $file_name;
$long_file_name = '/tmp/'.$file_name;
$state['dumper_long_file_name'] = $long_file_name;
$handle = fopen($long_file_name,'w') or die("bad file open");
fwrite($handle,$labels);    
fclose($handle);
```

The error I am getting is 
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: PHP_AUTH_USER
>   Filename: models/export_data_model.php
>   Line Number: 26

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are receiving is letting you know that there is no such key for `PHP_AUTH_USER` in the server superglobal.  This means base HTTP auth, sometimes used in CGI or defined in a webserver config like apache, isn't available/enabled.

[PHP_AUTH_USER not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663520/php-auth-user-not-set)

Note that the error level is a warning, so it isn't going to stop execution unless you have your error level set to strict.

Since you say that you are working on someone else's code, I would say this means the code was originally intended to use native webserver authentication rather than an authentication model defined in the code using a database.  You're going to need to find an alternative if you are deploying this somewhere else, like creating your own authentication mechanism using a persistency layer.

Docs for HTTP auth under Apache:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP documentation for `$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) states for `['PHP_AUTH_USER']`:

> When doing HTTP authentication this variable is set to the username provided by the user.

So what this tells me, is that there is no HTTP authentication taking place.

I suggest you read up on [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

Comment: I am starting to use PHP recently so do not understand most of the stuff. So when you say that during HTTP authentication the variables were set. Where can I check what they were set to.I mean is that the config.php file or the php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a notice because you aren't checking if $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] is set before referencing it. It's only a notice though, so it's not that critical.

Answer (score -1):

It tells you ***exactly*** what the error id in the error message.

`$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]` does not exist.

Comment: I believe the purpose of this question was **WHY** does that not exist?

Answer (score -1):

If you installed Apache2 , try this command:

```
sed -i "s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Comment: Can you explain what your solution is doing and why it resolves the issue?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).