# I need an opinion to replace with HTTP Basic AUTH with PHP

Tags: apache2, php, basic-authentication

In local computer i made php script that prompts users for their username and password through http basic auth. 
When i get username and password i use them to connect an api server.
However on prod server http basic auth is not working because php server api compiled as **FPM**. 
Since `PHP_AUTH_USER` does not work with FPM, i need an idea to alter that.
Recompiling PHP as apache mod, i mean server api: apache2handler is an idea but i have afraid to do it on a prod server.

Answer (score 0):

See answer here:
[PHP_AUTH_USER not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663520/php-auth-user-not-set/27229807)

in particular my last comment for PHP-FPM (checked and working with Symfony)

For an example in PHP see this:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php#L47