# Undefined index: PHP_AUTH_USER, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] not get

Tags: php, curl

I have set username and password in curl request but not get in request

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username" . ":" . "pwd");

$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
```

not get username and password using above $_server[''] please anyone help me

i get error like Undefined index: PHP_AUTH_USER

Comment: If you are using PHP 7, use [Coalesce operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm) `??`, to check and set default values for undefined variables/indexes etc

Comment: @☝️ I don't think *suppressing the error* is what's intended here…

Comment: i just send curl request of username and password but when i get it in other server  it's give a error Undefined index: PHP_AUTH_USER

Comment: check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663520/php-auth-user-not-set

Comment: it's working on local but not in server

Comment: That very specifically depends on your server and whether/how your server passes the information through to PHP. See the duplicate for possible solutions. If that doesn't work, we'll need to know more about your server. Perhaps you need to talk to the people that administer your server.

Comment: My Server API" is CGI/FCGI, so there is a any way to use HTTP auth from PHP